# Freeform timing out on return page

Tags: forms, solspace-freeform

I have EE v2.5.3 and Freeform Pro 4.0.10 among other things.

When submitting forms with admin notify turned on I get a server timeout error. The form data still submits to the db and I still get a notification email but the server hangs and eventually times out instead of loading the return page.

If I turn on admin notify it works properly, but obviously no notification, which I very much need.

Comment: What settings do you have in place in your install for mailing? SMTP? PHPMail?

Comment: SMTP in place. It was working last week. Not sure what happened.

Comment: I'm using the Freeform Pro notifications. Never actually set up the SMPT stuff for control panel emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like it's an issue on your server since it was working and now is not.

I'd first test to see if you are having timeouts when sending from the [**Communicate page**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/communicate.html) in EE. If you can't send from the Communicate page, enable [**Email Debugging**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/email_configuration.html#enable-email-debugging) to see what's going on.

Also check your PHP error logs to see what you see. An error related to the timeout may exist there.

If necessary, contact your host to see if they have changed anything on the server related to PHPMail/SMTP (I'm not clear from your comment which one you are using exactly)... Send them the info you find in the debugging and logs.

Comment: The host did change something. Switched to Sendmail in the mail settings and it works now. Thank you.